# How to get "id" from the json object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "id": "order_I4rOK0TqFk3nxF",
    "entity": "order",
    "amount": 200000,
    "amount_paid": 0,
    "amount_due": 200000,
    "currency": "INR",
    "receipt": "recipt by me",
    "offer_id": null,
    "status": "created",
    "attempts": 0,
    "notes": [],
    "created_at": 1633263345
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to Json Object, then access properties:

```
var jsonData = 
{"id":"order_I4rOK0TqFk3nxF","entity":"order","amount":200000,"amount_paid":0,"amount_due":200000,"currency":"INR","receipt":"recipt by me","offer_id":null,"status":"created","attempts":0,"notes":[],"created_at":1633263345}

var id = JSON.parse(jsonData).id;
```